# Issues with dming a user if they send a command

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I am trying to create a discord bot that can serve a multitude of purposes. Right now, I need some help with dming the user if they use the !help prefix. I tried multiple ways of dming the user & they lead to nowhere.

Here is my code:

```
const Discord = require("discord.js");
const config = require("./config.json");

const client = new Discord.Client({intents: ["GUILDS", "GUILD_MESSAGES"]});

const prefix = "!";

client.on("messageCreate", function(message) {
  if (message.author.bot) return;
  if (!message.content.startsWith(prefix)) return;

  const commandBody = message.content.slice(prefix.length);
  const args = commandBody.split(' ');
  const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();

  if (command === "") {
    const timeTaken = Date.now() - message.createdTimestamp;
    message.reply("e")
  }
});

client.on('message', message => {
    if (message.content === 'help') {
        messageCreate.author.send('Help')
    }
});


client.login(config.BOT_TOKEN);
```

Comment: What have you tried and what specifically goes wrong?

Comment: I tried using member.send, the following:

Comment: `client.on('message', msg => {   
  const member = guild.members.cache.get(targetUsers.id)
  if(command === "help") {
    member.roles.add(role)
    member.send("Message here")
  }
})
`

Comment: using the guilds intent, and way more stuff.

Answer (score 0):

Note your code here:

```js
    if (message.content === 'help') {
        messageCreate.author.send('Help')
    }
```

What is messageCreate defined as? Try replacing `messageCreate` with just `message` in the above excerpt.